# Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute while running java -jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have successfully built my Spring MVC project with `mvn clean package` by following [this tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).

Now I am trying to run the service with:

```
mvn clean package && java -jar target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar
```

But I get this error:

**Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar**

Am I missing something?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Answer (score 157, accepted):

If you are working with Spring Boot this will solve your problem:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

[Reference Guide | Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html)

Comment: Simply adding the above code and using `mvn package` did not work for me. I had to use `mvn package spring-boot:repackage` ,which created the standalone application.

Comment: When i did this my integrationtests failed due to NoClassDeff... Adding <phase>post-integration-test</phase> to the execution solved it for me

Comment: `mvn package spring-boot:repackage` resolved my issue. Thanks for the doc attached above.

Comment: mvn package worked for me. I didn't have to do mvn spring-boot:repackage. I am using spring-boot 1.5.9.RELEASE + java 8 on mac os. If you have do mvn spring-boot:repackage, then there is no need to add the repackage goal in your pom.xml. The whole point of adding the repackage goal in pom.xml is that maven will automatically call spring-boot:package when you call mvn package.

Comment: If you properly inherit from [`spring-boot-starter-parent`](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-starter-parent), then you won't have to do the `repackage` step.

Comment: It's not an obligation to inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent. Especially in big project developers come with their own parent pom for managing dependencies and controlling jar hell.

Answer (score 21):

You might be missing Spring Boot Maven Plugin.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to specifiy it in your pom.xml - This will make your jar executable with all dependencies (replace `your.main.class`):

```
<!-- setup jar manifest to executable with dependencies -->
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>  
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

check the order of

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

it should be above

dockerfile-maven-plugin else repackage will happen

this solved my problem of no main attribute in manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `maven-jar-plugin` in which you need to add `manifest` tag.

Answer (score 1):

For spring boot, I've created a **MANIFEST.MF** file inside **META-INF** folder.

in my STS IDE, I placed the META-INFO folder inside the **src/main/resources** folder
like so:

[image: screenshot from STS IDE (eclipse project)]

the content of the MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: bankim
Implementation-Version: 1.5.6.RELEASE
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Yourname
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.bankim
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.5.6.RELEASE
Implementation-Vendor: Pivotal Software, Inc.
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.bankim.BankimApplication
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131
Implementation-URL: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/bankim/
```

1. Every mention of "bankim"/"Bankim" refers to my project name, so replace it with your project name that
2. take special note of the "Start-Class" value.  it should contain the "path" to the class that has your **main** method.
3. the row:
   Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLaunchershould be left as-is.

****the above manifest was created for me by using the "spring-boot-maven-plugin"  mentioned above by "Mradul Pandey" (answered Sep 2 '15 at 4:50)

Hope this helps

Comment: You should not do this manually. When configured properly, spring-boot plugin creates this for you. It is puzzling though that not the same solution works for everyone. I had to add the executions part to the plugin e.g. else it failed.

Comment: i didn't create it manually, (see mentioned in step 3). 
but yes, not sure what caused this.  it's been a while ...

Answer (score 1):

`java -jar target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar` command assumes the provided jar is *executable*. In an *executable* jar, the `main` method is defined in `MANIFEST.MF` file. Given that you don't have a `MANIFEST.MF` file, an additional command-line argument can be passed to specify the class containing the `main` method.

A command like `java -cp target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar com.pkg.subpkg.MainClass` would serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` but still I was getting the error regarding main class.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Finally I had to use the `maven-jar-plugin` and add the `mainClass`

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.org.proj.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

And it was good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Use `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

and be sure you set `property start-class` in the pom.xml

```
<properties>
      <!-- The main class to start by executing "java -jar" -->
      <start-class>org.example.DemoApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

Alternatively, the main class can be defined as the mainClass element of the spring-boot-maven-plugin in the plugin section of your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>repackage</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                         <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin configuration is like mine (`below`), then, use `mvn package spring-boot:repackage`.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your main class on MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Main-Class: com.example.MainClassApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> **mvn package spring-boot:repackage**
>
> hit this command before target dir
> then use jar file

.