# Mvn clean package not creating JAR-File properly

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

> note: I tried out the suggested answers in the "possible-duplicated"-questions, they did sadly not help me. I edited my question a bit.

I set up a Spring-Boot application (that can be executed from the `Spring Tool Suite` IDE). Now I wanted to build the jar-file and execute it. What I tried:

```
cd %path_to_my_project_root%
mvn clean package
cd target
java -jar myApp.jar
```

The error is (translated, maybe incorrect wording):

> no main manifest attribute in myApp.jar

I have tried different solutions suggested on different platforms (e.g. [here](http://roufid.com/no-main-manifest-attribute-in-app-jar/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620342/failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-while-running-java-jar)). Yet, as far as I understood, it seems to be a problem with my `POM.xml`.

**My Pom:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myApp</name>
    <description>desc</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>

     <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>ng</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/ui</workingDirectory>
                        <argument>
                            <argument>build</argument>
                        </argument>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

I looked up my `Manifest.MF` and this was the content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: myApp
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Built-By: me
Implementation-Vendor-Id: myPackage
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.0
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_191
Implementation-URL: my_Url
```

**What I seem to be missing:**

I looked up the `jar`-file and there were a few things I noticed:

- I am missing a `.jar.original`-file
- There is not `Spring-Boot-Version`, `Main-Class`, `Start-Class` and no `Boot-Inf` argument in my `Manifest.MF`
- My `jar` contains only three things: `META-INF`, `com` (the classes, compiled) and the `application.properties`-file. There is usually a lot more stuff in it.

**My Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://external.url/dbname?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: Or simply provide an entrypoint when calling java -jar : `java -jar myApp.jar your.own.ClassWithMainMethod`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a spring boot executable jar in a Production environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886083/how-do-i-run-a-spring-boot-executable-jar-in-a-production-environment) ; there's an `executable` tag you can set on the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin configuration to make the jar executable, seems like the most appropriate for your context

Comment: @Mark I'm confused about this - i am going to try this but I had an earlier pom.xml (going to add it in my question) where these things were not necessary

Comment: @Aaron Adding the executable-flag did not change the outcome

Comment: @Aaron You can't specify the entrypoint when using `-jar`. Did you mean `-cp` instead?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Wow, I was sure you could, weird. I guess I haven't executed a jar from the command line for too long. `java -cp myApp.jar your.own.ClassWithMainMethod` it is then, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `<pluginManagement>`-tag in the plugins and had no problem building it afterwards. I have no idea what that Tag does (that it should not do) but it seems like this was the trigger for the problem. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me there.

Comment: I can't believe this Answer helped me after two days of fiddling around with the assembly plugin not creating my -jar-with-dependency.jar. Even this Answer is almost three years old. Thank you very much sharing this information. This <pluginManagement> tag is created by default when i create a new project with maven on the terminal - and i have no idea why it is in my pom.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing this maven property:

```
<start-class>com.demo.MainClass</start-class>
```

(This must contain your Main-class that calls `SpringApplication.run(..)`)

Comment: I tried adding this in my `properties`-Tag, it sadly did not change the outcome - now he says, that he cannot find the class "com.demo.MainClass" (ofc. I changed the name of that path

Comment: You need to change that to the class that contains your `main()` method.

Comment: I did, that did not help out sadly