# SpringBoot no main manifest attribute (maven)

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, manifest, spring-boot-maven-plugin

When running my jar file: `java -jar target/places-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I'm getting the next error :

> no main manifest attribute, in target/places-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

The `pom.xml` contains the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.places.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I also tried to create a `MANIFEST.MF` file and specifying the class, but it didnt help.

In addition, I also tried:

```
<properties>
      <!-- The main class to start by executing "java -jar" -->
      <start-class>com.places.Main</start-class>
</properties>
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class,args);
    }
}
```

Any idea what else can I try?

Comment: do you have a main @SpringBootApplication class?

Comment: Of course, inside the Main class. I put in in the original post

Comment: can you specify more info, spring-boot version & maven version.

Comment: maven3 and springboot 2.1.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute while running java -jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620342/failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-while-running-java-jar)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Try adding `repackage` goal to execution goals.

Otherwise you would need to call the plugin explicitly as `mvn package spring-boot:repackage`.

With the goal added, you have to call only `mvn package`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.places.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It helped ! Can you explain why I need to package it ?

Comment: If you have `spring-boot-starter-parent` in you pom, you don't need to define `repackage` goal in the plugin. Official doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#repackage

Comment: The reason for this is that you are no using spring as parent I assume you have it set on dependencyManagement, then  you have to explicit define which goal to be hooked for spring-boot-maven-plugin ir order to get an executable jar file. In this case repackage.

Comment: similar issue with multi module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833195/spring-boot-multi-module-spring-boot-maven-plugin-compilation-failure

Answer (score 47):

During the *Maven* `package` lifecycle phase, the *jar* archive is enhanced by *Spring Boot Maven Plugin* and the original *jar* file (that should have been built using the standard *maven-jar-plugin*) is replaced with an *enhanced* ***executable*** jar.

Hence you have either to issue the `spring-boot:repackage` goal yourself when building your module:

```
mvn package spring-boot:repackage
```

Or add the `goal` explicitly within the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.places.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can find more details about the *Spring Boot Maven Plugin* [`repackage` goal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#repackage) within the official documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/ajeetkumarv/healthlog I tried both repackage and plugin but did not work. main method is in application module

Comment: Hi @Ajeetkumar, could you report a new question with your build configuration and point it out. I will be glad to help.

Answer (score 25):

3 things:
- You have the parent entry in your pom.
- Verify that your plugin is in the build portion of the pom.
- You have a class with the @SpringBootApplicaion annotation.

pom.xml:

```
...  
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
...
```

And a class that looks something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify a parent *POM* e.g. :

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

During the package goal, the repackage goal will be executed and you'll then get an executable jar.

Answer (score 4):

Reback your *jar* or *war* using the following command:

`mvn package spring-boot:repackage`

Add the plugin in `plugins` parent node like below in *pom.xml*:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>                   
      <mainClass>com.sify.scdm.solutionconfigurator.ScdmApplication</mainClass>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
      <goals>
         <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

added build tag in pom.xml as below solved issue for me.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the plugin below.This worked for me

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <executions>
           <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
           <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                     <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                     <transformers>
                          <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                               <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
                               <manifestEntries>
                                    <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                                </manifestEntries>
                          </transformer>
                          <transformer
                                 implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                 <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                          </transformer>
                          <transformer
                                 implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                 <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                          </transformer>
                     </transformers>
                </configuration>
           </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```