# Vaadin + SpringBoot = no main manifest attribute, in file.war

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, vaadin, vaadin14

I have a webapp in Vaadin 14 LTS. When I run the webapp in INTELLIJ it runs normally (in development mode), but when I compile it in production mode with "mvn clean package -Pproduction" and then run with "java -jar smcweb.war" I get the message "no main manifest attribute, in smcweb.war".
I have several APIs created with SpringBoot and I can run them normally with "java -jar ..."

Something curious: I use the apexcharts chart library. When from INTELLIJ I execute the webapp with "spring-boot:run" it is shown in the console:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.4:run (default-cli) @ smcweb ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5230
                                 _                   _        
  __ _  _ __    ___ __  __  ___ | |__    __ _  _ __ | |_  ___ 
 / _` || '_ \  / _ \\ \/ / / __|| '_ \  / _` || '__|| __|/ __|
| (_| || |_) ||  __/ >  < | (__ | | | || (_| || |   | |_ \__ \
 \__,_|| .__/  \___|/_/\_\ \___||_| |_| \__,_||_|    \__||___/
       |_|
```

...instead of the typical Spring Boot console output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)
```

Below is the POM.xml file

PD: It is possible that some residue of PAYARA MICRO has been left in the POM.XML. Previously we deployed with PAYARA MICRO.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried some solutions in MAVEN, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867295/springboot-no-main-manifest-attribute-maven).
All of them without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to build a self contained system using java -jar a web application archive (war) is not the right format for your application. You should consider using jar and proper [spring boot configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-run-maven-vs-executable-jar) for it.

Additionally, the apex chart addon is providing a [banner.txt](https://github.com/appreciated/apexcharts-flow/blob/master/src/main/resources/banner.txt) which it shouldn't do, therefore you get the mentioned logo, instead of your own / spring boot's default.

Comment: Thanks Knoobie, I will check this documentation.